# Pure CSS fixed table header

Tags: html, css, sass, css-tables

New with CSS/SCSS
My table is wider than the screen will be so I want the header to move left and right with the rest of the table. I also want the header to stick to stay in place and not scroll up and down with the table so that if you scroll down to the right you can still know what columns those values belong to. And I am not able to make the table smaller. I'm using React and have tried [react-sticky-tables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky-table) but it didn't seem to work properly.

```css
.fixed_table_wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

.fixed_header{
    width: 500px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fixed_header tbody{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 100px;
}

.fixed_header thead tr {
   display: block;
}

.fixed_header thead {
  background: black;
  color:#fff;
}

.fixed_header th, .fixed_header td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 350px;

}
```

```html
<div class="fixed_table_wrapper">
<table class="fixed_header">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
      <th>Col 6</th>
      <th>Col 7</th>
      <th>Col 8</th>
      <th>Col 9</th>
      <th>Col 10</th>
      <th>Col 11</th>
      <th>Col 12</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 2-0</td>
      <td>row 2-1</td>
      <td>row 2-2</td>
      <td>row 2-3</td>
      <td>row 2-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 3-0</td>
      <td>row 3-1</td>
      <td>row 3-2</td>
      <td>row 3-3</td>
      <td>row 3-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 4-0</td>
      <td>row 4-1</td>
      <td>row 4-2</td>
      <td>row 4-3</td>
      <td>row 4-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 5-0</td>
      <td>row 5-1</td>
      <td>row 5-2</td>
      <td>row 5-3</td>
      <td>row 5-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td><td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 6-0</td>
      <td>row 6-1</td>
      <td>row 6-2</td>
      <td>row 6-3</td>
      <td>row 6-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td><td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td><td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td><td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td><td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td><td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td><td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td><td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td><td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td><td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td><td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td><td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0 asdhjkl;wejf;lkjs</td>
      <td>row 7-1 asdhjkl;wejf;lkjs</td>
      <td>row 7-2 asdhjkl;343gwefgsdwejf;lkjs</td>
      <td>row 7-3 asdhjkl;wejf;lkjs</td>
      <td>row 7-4 asdhjkl;wejf;lkjs</td>
      <td>row 1-0 asdhjkl;wejf;lkjs</td>
      <td>row 1-1 asdhjkl;wejf;lkjs</td><td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-2 asdhjkl;wejf;lkjs</td>
      <td>row 1-3 asdhjkl;wejf;lkjs</td>
      <td>row 1-4 asdhjkl;wejf;lkjs</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a table. Here is my criteria;

1. Header must be fixed.
2. Vertical and Horizontal scrolling. The table I'm working with is wider than the screen itself.
3. Having fixed column size is okay.

Basically scroll left-right, up-down, and still have the header at the top to reference what cell you are looking at.

I realize that the only way to add a fixed column width. In the attached codepen I can't seem to get the size of the columns to match. From what I can tell, the longer data in the columns is causing the alignment issue. I've tried `overflow: hidden;` to prevent this but it seems to ignore it. It also seems to ignore me trying to set width. [If you would kindly take a look at my code-pen attempt.](https://codepen.io/andrewmckeighan/pen/rQxJvE)

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the actual question itself. Preferably as a [MCVE]

Comment: @JonP it has it. in the code pen...

Comment: We prefer the code **in the question itself**. You can use the `<>` button in the editor to create a StackSnippet in the question itself, which is very similar to code pen. Don't make us go off site to find important information. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry @JonP, didn't know you could do that. Thanks for letting me know. I added the snippet to the question and tried to clarify my question even further.

Answer (score 0):

For sticky table head, there is an npm package for this that I recommend that will save you time and energy. Check it out: react-sticky-table-thead All you have to do is to wrap a component around your table like:

```
<StickyHeader>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Head</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</StickyHeader>
```